# Configuring Spring to directory structure rather than *.html or other pattern

Tags: java, spring

I want my spring application to access url like http://myapplication.com/app1/feature/ rather than http://myapplication.com/app1/feature.html 
So basically how should I configure. 
My Current config is below it works with *.html 
web.xml

[image: web.xml]
and it gives 404 error it I do map it to  * .* etc

Comment: That image is barely legible. Can you paste in the XML?

Comment: I got the answer I changed it to
<url-pattern>/application/*</url-pattern>
Thanks Reimeus , your help is highly appreciated. I posted as image as when I  was posting xml  , due to html content was not proper , moreover I tried with code tag but couldn't get much . Would love to know how to we post xml while replying or asking question here on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

> and it gives 404 error it I do map it to * .* etc

The [servlet spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html) is very strict about what's allowed in a `url-pattern`. You're probably looking for `/*`, which will direct all requests to the `DispatcherServlet`, regardless of the path. Then it's up to you to define what happens.

For reference, "Specification of Mappings" (12.2) allows the following patterns:

- A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ suffix is used for 
  path mapping.
- A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension mapping.
- The empty string ("") is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the 
  application's context root, i.e., requests of the form `http://host:port/<contextroot>/`. In this case the path info is ’/’ and the servlet path and context path is 
  empty string (““).
- A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default" servlet of the 
  application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path 
  and the path info is null.
- All other strings are used for exact matches only